# AbstractFieldFactory warning in magnolia log

Tags: java, magnolia

I invoke this `ImportCommandAction` which is defined as public class `ImportCommandAction <D extends ActionDefinition> extends AbstractVersionAction<D>` as an action on a Page. The custom import action has its own VersionName class and overrides the getBeanItemClass(). Every time I invoke this class I get in the log an entry

> WARN magnolia.ui.form.field.factory.AbstractFieldFactory: BeanItem
>   doesn't have any property for id versionName, returning default
>   property.

I do not understand this warning and to what id the `ui.form.field.factory.AbstractFieldFactory` refers. The class opens a dialog form and lists all the versions (commits) from and internal git repository.

Class code:

```
    public ImportCommandAction(
            D definition, AppContext appContext, LocationController locationController,
            UiContext uiContext, FormDialogPresenter formDialogPresenter, 
            AbstractJcrNodeAdapter nodeAdapter, SimpleTranslator i18n, 
            ContentConnector contentConnector)
    {
            super(definition, locationController, uiContext, formDialogPresenter, i18n);
            this.nodeAdapter = nodeAdapter;
            this.appContext = appContext;
            this.dialogID = "ui-contentapp:code:ImportCommandAction.selectVersion";
            this.contentConnector = contentConnector;
        }

        @Override
        protected Class getBeanItemClass() {
            return VersionName.class;
        }

        @Override
        protected FormDialogDefinition buildNewComponentDialog() 
        throws ActionExecutionException, RepositoryException {
        ConfiguredFormDefinition form = new ConfiguredFormDefinition();

        ConfiguredTabDefinition tab = new ConfiguredTabDefinition();
        tab.setName("versions");

        SelectFieldDefinition select = new SelectFieldDefinition();
        select.setName(VersionName.PROPERTY_NAME_VERSION_NAME);
        select.setSortOptions(false);
        tab.addField(select); //more code follows
        }

        @Override
        protected Node getNode() throws RepositoryException {
             return nodeAdapter.getJcrItem();
        }

        protected String getVersionName() {
            return (String) getItem()
            .getItemProperty(VersionName.PROPERTY_NAME_VERSION_NAME)
            .getValue();
        }

        /**
         * Simple POJO used to access user selection from dialog, 
         * see {@link com.vaadin.data.util.BeanItem}.
         */
        protected class VersionName {

            protected final static String PROPERTY_NAME_VERSION_NAME = "versionName";

            private String versionName;

            public String getVersionName() {
                return versionName;
            }

            public void setVersionName(String versionName) {
                this.versionName = versionName;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Ana, I didn't quite get the question. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Hi @Ducaz035. I invoke this ImportCommandAction which is defined as 
`public class ImportCommandAction <D extends ActionDefinition> extends AbstractVersionAction<D> ` as an action on a Page. The custom import action has its own VersionName class and overrides the `getBeanItemClass()`. Every time I invoke this class I get in the log an entry _WARN  magnolia.ui.form.field.factory.AbstractFieldFactory: BeanItem doesn't have any property for id versionName, returning default property_ 
I do not understand this warning and to what id the _ui.form.field.factory.AbstractFieldFactory_ refers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the injected item to the fieldFactory cannot find a property with defition#name. In your case defition#name is versionName and it fallback to a default value for the sake of not failing the fieldFactory all together. I'd debug which field is the cause of this behaviour and continue the investigation from there.

Hope that helps,

Cheers

Comment: Thanks @Ducaz035. 
It appear line  `final String label = dialogDefinition.getLabel();` in `private void buildView(FormDialogDefinition dialogDefinition)` is generating the `WARN magnolia.ui.form.field.factory.AbstractFieldFactory: BeanItem doesn't have any property for id versionName, returning default property.` How can I find out what properties the BeanItem has and how do I add this property to it?